# How to set index while have only one column in big data using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I just wanna set India as a index and want to remove first column. How can i do that please tell me if anyone knows.

[image]

Comment: You could better your code here, It's not good to past image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve only one column in the dataset? Else you’ve to do it while reading csv.
If I understand what you want.
try   this.

```
rd = pd.read_csv('world_population.csv', index_col="india")
rd.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the index with [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and drop the existing index with `drop=True`.

So, something like

```
a.set_index('India', inplace=True, drop=True)
```